# Join two tables with no relation postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this statement which you can see

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM
(SELECT m.* FROM microposts AS m) AS t1
  FULL JOIN
(SELECT r.* FROM ratings AS r) AS t2
ON true
```

I am using Rails and connecting to the database raw, but the output removes duplicate named columns eg user_id etc from the second table and is still giving results in the second table in regards to the first even though there is no relation. Eg

```
+------+-----------+-------+--------+
| m.id | m.content | r.id  | rating |  
+------+-----------+-------+--------+
|  1   |  "hello"  |  10   |   5    |
+------+-----------+-------+--------+
```

There is no relation between table `m` and `r`

I would like A output of something like this

```
+------+-----------+------+---------+
| m.id | m.content | r.id | rating  |  
+------+-----------+------+---------+
|  1   |  "hello"  | null |   null  |
| null |   null    |  5   |    4    |
|  2   |   "gday"  | null |   null  |
+------+-----------+------+---------+
....................... etc
```

Comment: This looks like task for `union all`, not `join`.

Comment: But you need matching number of columns? Rename columns and match them?

Comment: You need exactly the same number of columns and they need to be of the same type. no equal names are needed

Comment: You can always `select a, b, c, null, null, null from t1 union all select null, null, null, d, e, f from t2`; you may need to cast null values to appropriate types.

Comment: Ok this sound good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rather exotic way to say UNION ALL

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* 
FROM
   (SELECT m.* FROM microposts AS m) AS t1
FULL JOIN
   (SELECT r.* FROM ratings AS r) AS t2
ON false
```

Contrary, `ON true` will create a cartesian product.

Comment: I tried this. I think rails may be interfering with something

Comment: Why the subqueries? Can't we just `SELECT m.*, r.* FROM microposts AS m FULL JOIN ratings AS r ON false`?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, .. just copied from OP. Probably they are for a reason, complex subquery or something, just simplified for the question.

Comment: Yeah so I did A raw connection through pgadmin and rails is bunging the call